# In Unix, can I run 'make' in a directory without cd'ing to that directory first?

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

In Unix, can I run `make` in a directory without `cd`'ing to that directory first?

Answer (score 392, accepted):

`make -C /path/to/dir`

Comment: Grump - that isn't in standard make; it must be a GNU extension.  Since you say Linux and Unix, it isn't clear which you want, but the -C option won't work on Solaris 10 (/usr/ccs/bin/make), AIX (/usr/bin/make), or HP-UX 11.23 (/usr/bin/make).  Still, 1 out of 4 isn't too bad.

Comment: It works in BSD make as well, so its not just a GNU extension.

Comment: make sure 'C' is in upper case.

Comment: Or use `--directory=` which does the same.

Answer (score 106):

As noted in other answers, make(1) has a `-C`  option for this; several commands have similar options (e.g. tar).  It is useful to note that for other commands which lack such options the following can be used:

```
(cd /dir/path && command-to-run)
```

This runs the command in a sub-shell which first has its working directory changed (while leaving the working directory of the parent shell alone).  Here `&&`  is used instead of `;`  to catch error cases where the directory can not be changed.

Answer (score 23):

If the reason you don't want to cd to a directory is because you need to stay in the current directory for a later task, you can use pushd and popd:

```
pushd ProjectDir ; make ; popd
```

That goes into the ProjectDir, runs make, and goes back to where you were.

Answer (score 11):

Also you may use:

```
make --directory /path/to/dir
```

Answer (score -4):

makefile:

```
all:
    gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -std=gnu99 -g src/test.c -o build/test

run:
    ./build/test
```

or

```
run:
    ./../build/test
```

etc.

Comment: The answer completely missed the question - it is about how to invoke make, not how to write makefile.