# Specifying path to "makefile" using "make" command

Tags: makefile

I would like to run a makefile from another place in the file system. How do  I pass the location of the makefile to make?

if I stand in "/" and I would like to run a makefile that resists in "/dir/dir2/dir3/makefile", how do I add that to the make command?

I tried:

```
make --file=dir/dir2/dir3/makefile
```

but it did not worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Unix, can I run 'make' in a directory without cd'ing to that directory first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453447/in-unix-can-i-run-make-in-a-directory-without-cding-to-that-directory-first)

Comment: ok, so `-C` is not guaranteed to work? I can't make it work with `/lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/proverbot9001/CompCert/configure x86_64-linux && make clean -C /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/proverbot9001/CompCert` only `./configure x86_64-linux && make` seems to work.

Comment: does `make -C` do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

All relative paths **in** the makefile will be relative to your current directory and not the directory of the makefile.

Assuming that you understand that and what you want to do is still going to work then you want the `-f` flag to specify the makefile to use. (Which is in the man page, the manual and the `--help` output.)

If, instead, what you mean is you want to `cd` to somewhere else and run make then perhaps you are looking for `(cd /some/path && make)`?

Comment: Maybe the cd suggestion fits best. I guess that, the difference is whether I want the compiled files to be in the same folder as the make file (which would be the cd example), or if I want the files to be in the same dir where I stand. Am I right?

Comment: More than that. If you have a rule in the makefile that says `foo: foo.c` that will create a file `foo` in the current directory but will also look for `foo.c` in the current directory and it isn't going to be there.

Comment: I have been messing around with my Makefile trying to get `make` to recognize `CFLAGS` arguments I specified therein. But it didn't seem those args were getting passed to `make`. So I removed my local `Makefile` and ran `make` again, and it continued to run the same command (`cc -o ex4.c -o ex4`). I was trying to pass `-g -Wall` via `CFLAGS`. Is there some master `Makefile` hanging around my OS?!

Comment: No. Built-in rules. See [Catalogue of Built-In Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Comment: ok, so `-C` is not guaranteed to work? I can't make it work with `/lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/proverbot9001/CompCert/configure x86_64-linux && make clean -C /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/proverbot9001/CompCert` only `./configure x86_64-linux && make` seems to work.

Comment: does `make -C` do it?

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `-C` flag to specify the path to your makefile. This way you can execute it from a different directory.
The `-f` flag has a different use. With that flag you can execute a makefile with a name other than `makefile`.

Comment: This did the trick for me, I generated my Makefile with cmake and then wanted to build from another directory

Comment: ok, so `-C` is not guaranteed to work? I can't make it work with `/lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/proverbot9001/CompCert/configure x86_64-linux && make clean -C /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/proverbot9001/CompCert` only `./configure x86_64-linux && make` seems to work.

Comment: does `make -C` do it?